# How can I trace all api request made through my android app

Tags: android, react-native, okhttp, fresco, firebase-performance

In my android app, I'm using 3rd party libraries like fresco and okhttp3. I want to trace the response of every request made through these libraries. And i want to do it globally

I'm using react-native also in my app, and i wants to trace the response of each api call made from react-native code like firebase performance monitoring tool.

Any idea how firebase is doing this?

In okhttp3 i can add interceptor to track these, but request made through fresco and react-native I'm not able to track like this

Comment: If you want to monitor request for debug purpose, you could use fiddler to capture all the requests made from mobile phones

Comment: @SangeetSuresh thanks for you reply. But I need to monitor from users mobile. I've integrated statsd for android, and I want to send all the network trace to send to statsd server using UDP protocol.

Comment: well you could have at least stated you need remote logging in the initial question, instead of downvoting valid answers later

Answer (score 3):

@JM India

Please check [Android Snooper](https://github.com/jainsahab/AndroidSnooper) library. If I understand you problem correctly this is what you are looking for.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: Thanks Sandy, I will try this :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Charles](https://www.charlesproxy.com) . This tool is powerful to trace all request and response. It works for all platform.

Answer (score 0):

In development, you can use [Stetho](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/#features) to trace any calls via a [Network Intereceptor](http://facebook.github.io/stetho/#for-okhttp-3-x).

There will be different ways to get the active OkHttp instance for different frameworks e.g. [ReactNative](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35189361/1542667).

Comment: Thanks, but ReactNative stopped supporting OkHttpClientProvider.getOkHttpClient() and i Stetho won't fulfil my requirement.

Comment: Seems to be there https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/0.48-stable/ReactAndroid/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/modules/network/OkHttpClientProvider.java

Answer (score -1):

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/jpsanders/2013/04/03/configuring-fiddler-to-be-a-proxy-for-android-emulators-in-eclipse/

here's how I used to do it. All you have to do is set up a proxy using fiddler and configure your emulator to use it